# For a web site set to run with a SSL certificate, what is the purpose of SSL settings in IIS Manager and what do they do?

Tags: ssl, iis-manager

I have sites set to run securly with a SSL certificate. In the IIS Manager when clicking the site node I get in the middle of the screen a list of features having different settings that can be set. One of them is called SSL Settings. Double clicking shows a page stating:

> This page lets you modify the SSL settings for the content of a websit or application

It gives options of a check box `Require SSL` and a radio list `Client Certificate` with three options, 1. `Ignore`, 2. `Accept`, 3. `Require`.

What's the significance of each option and what do they do?

I tried searching in Google but didn't find anything.

Comment: Why was this down voted? I've searched the web to find an explanation of these options and found nothing!

Comment: Agreed, I upvoted it, and favorited this

Comment: @Rishi Thank you!:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Ignore if you do not want to accept a client certificate even if a client presents one.

Select Accept to accept client certificates.

Select Require to require client certificates. To use Require Client Certificates, you must enable Require SSL.

Taken from here
[Specify Whether to Use Client Certificates (IIS 7)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753983(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! Thru your link I got to this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732367(v=ws.10).aspx That explains the Require SSL Check box.

Answer (score 0):

This section are some further settings on IIS for a web application once you have received a certificate to make a website secure (HTTPS).

These instructions may put some context to the SSL settings area:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/324069/how-to-set-up-an-https-service-in-iis

Comment: So if my site is configured to use SSL and I don't check Require SSL, it work with or without SSL?